# OpenPGP js returns [object Object] on message decryption

Tags: javascript, object, encryption, openpgp, openpgp.js

I'm trying to decrypt messages with the decrypt function in OpenPGP.js but the 'data' field on the returned object only contains [object Object]. I've tried JSON.stringify but that does nothing.
I've read the docs and it says that the 'data' field should be of type String by default.

Here's my code:

```
async function generateKeys(name, email) {
  const key = await openpgp.generateKey({
    userIds: { name: name, email: email },
  })
  return { public: key.publicKeyArmored, private: key.privateKeyArmored }
}

export async function decryptTest() {
  // Creating 2 users
  const user1 = await generateKeys('user1', 'user1@mail.com')
  const user2 = await generateKeys('user22', 'user2@mail.com')

  // Creating Key objects for both users

  // User1 Key Objects

  const user1PrivateKeyObject = await openpgp.readKey({
    armoredKey: user1.private,
  })
  const user1PublicKeyObject = await openpgp.readKey({
    armoredKey: user1.public,
  })

  //User2 Key Objects

  const user2PrivateKeyObject = await openpgp.readKey({
    armoredKey: user2.private,
  })
  const user2PublicKeyObject = await openpgp.readKey({
    armoredKey: user2.public,
  })

  // Creating Message object
  const messageObj = openpgp.Message.fromText({
    text: 'This is a message',
  })

  // Encrypting message with User1 private key
  const encryptedMessage = await openpgp.encrypt({
    message: messageObj,
    publicKeys: user2PublicKeyObject,
    privateKeys: user1PrivateKeyObject,
  })

  // Decrypting message

  // Creating Message object from armored string
  const encryptedMessageObj = await openpgp.readMessage({
    armoredMessage: encryptedMessage,
  })

  // Decrypting Message object with User2 Private Key Object
  const decryptedMessage = await openpgp.decrypt({
    message: encryptedMessageObj,
    privateKeys: user2PrivateKeyObject,
  })

  console.log(decryptedMessage)
}
```

Comment: [`Message.fromText`](https://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/Message.html#.fromText) expects a string, not an object.

Comment: Thank you very much. Interestingly enough it didn't throw an error and encrypted it even though I passed in the wrong argument.